# Failed to create a special random-disturbed initial condition for partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, random, splines, initialization

I try to use `BSplineFunction` to creat a initial condition for `NDSolve` which has periodic boundary condition, that is realized by producing a coarse grid of random number:

```
ini = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True];
```

`SplineClosed -> True` makes sure I can use it to consist with periodic boundary conditions in `NDSolve`.

I get into trouble: my `BSplineFunction` seems to be not a function of x and y. How can I describe it to be a function of x and y on a square domain with side length L (see my code)? I think that is the reason why `NDSolve` complains about when I try to use a spline surface acting as initial condition.

Working example:

```
Off[NDSolve::mxsst];
Clear["Global`*"]
L = 15;
c = -(1/20);
tmax = 1000;
a = 1/10;
b = 1;
m = 25;
ini = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True];

sol = First[ h /. NDSolve[{D[h[x, y, t], t] +
Div[-a*h[x, y, t]^3*Grad[h[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
Div[(b*m*h[x, y, t]^2*
Grad[h[x, y, t], {x, y}])/(2*(1 + b*h[x, y, t])^2), {x, y}] + 
Div[h[x, y, t]^3*Grad[Laplacian[h[x, y, t], {x, y}], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0,
h[0, y, t] == h[L, y, t], h[x, 0, t] == h[x, L, t],
h[x, y, 0] == ini[x, y]},
h, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax},
Method -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}, 
MaxStepFraction -> 1/50]]
```

I have the following error:

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: "!({NDSolve[{<<1>>}, h, {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}, {t, 0, 1000}, Method -> {\"BDF\", \"MaxDifferenceOrder\" -> 1}, MaxStepFraction -> *FractionBox[(1), (50)]]}) is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks. What is your mean by "fix" `ini`? I am confusing that when I try `ini[0, 7] == ini[L, 7]`, MMA give me **False**. With `SplineClosed -> True`, I want to obtain a random disturbance which has periodicity at the sides of the square-domain [0,L]*[0,L], ini(0,y)=ini(L,y) and ini(x,0)=ini(x,L). With ur `ini = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True][##] &;` `NDSlove` prompts >NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction::ddim: Data {{{0.993342},...,<<40>>,...,<<49>>,<<51>>} is not a rectangular tensor with dimensions {100,50}. How can I fix it?

Comment: The result of `BSplineFunction` is a parametric surface, with domain of each parameter normalized to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an `ini` that will evaluate to a numerical value when evaluated as `ini[x, y]`, one has to define it as

```
ini[x_, y_] = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True][x, y]
```

It is important to use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html?q=Set) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in this case, as one doesn't want to use new random numbers every time `ini` is evaluated.
With this definition of `ini`

```
ini[0, 7] == ini[L, 7]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

But one will get a new error when evaluating the rest of your code, because the output of `ini` is a `List` with a single entry instead of the single value expected by `NDSolve`. Therefore you have to replace

```
ini[x, y]
```

with

```
First@ini[x, y]
```

in your code for `sol`.

---

## Edit:

Maybe

```
random = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[]}, {x, 0, L, L/10}, {y, 0, L, L/10}];
random[[All, -1, -1]] = random[[All, 1, -1]];
random[[-1, All, -1]] = random[[1, All, -1]];

iniIF = Interpolation[Flatten[random, 1]];
ini[x_, y_] := 1 + c*iniIF[x, y]
```

will be more in accordance with your intentions.
Or something like

```
ini[x_, y_] = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], 
  SplineClosed -> True][x/L, y/L]
```

Comment: @ Karsten7. I have read the link you provided. I guess you might miss something in `ini[x_, y_] = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True][x, y]` during your copy&paste. Because when I use it by itself, I have this error: >Set::write: Tag Function in (1+c BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1,{30,30,1}],SplineClosed->True][##1]&)[x_,y_] is Protected. >>

Comment: @lxy You got that error because `ini` already has another definition. Please clear the old definition with `Clear@ini` and try again.

Comment: @ Karsten7. Yes, with `Clear` I get `True`. But, I have a bewilderment when I try `L = 4 \[Pi]; c = -(1/20);` `ini[x_, y_] =1+c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {30, 30, 1}], SplineClosed -> True][x, y];` `ini[0, 7] == ini[L, 7]`, MMA gives **False**. However, `L = 12`,or other integer it gives **True**. Very strange!

Comment: Maybe plotting `ini´ will help to clarify: `Plot[ini[x, 7], {x, 0, 15}]` & `Plot3D[Flatten@ini[x, y], {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}]`. Why should ini[0, 7] == ini[4 \[Pi], 7] be `True`?

Comment: @lxy Please see my edit and clarify if this `ini` has the appropriate properties.

Comment: @ Karsten7.I assume I am being very silly when I try to use `RandomReal[]` and `BSplineFunction` as my random number generator for my random disturbance. I think `ini[0, 7] == ini[4 [Pi], 7]` should be true because `L = 4 \[Pi]` is the side length of the square domain whose periodicity is given by `SplineClosed -> True`. Thanks again!

Comment: @ Karsten7. Your answer in the **Edit** is correct in that it fantastically produces a random disturbace surface. However, I was unable to use it as an known-condition for `NSlove`. e.g. `NSolve[NIntegrate[c1 + ini[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}] == L^2, c1, Reals]` from which I want get the value of c1. However, I can do `NIntegrate[ini[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}]`. This is my last intention.

Comment: The error you describe in your last comment has nothing to do with `ini`. `NSolve[NIntegrate[c1, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}] == L^2, c1, Reals]` would give you the same error. Try `f1[c1_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[c1 + ini[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}]` `NMinimize[(f1[c1] - L^2)^2, c1]` instead.